# Firebase admin SDK node - wildcard usage in reference

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

Is it possible to listen for child_added in the admin SDK while using a wildcard in the ref? In cloud functions, I could use "{random}" but this does not work in Node.js. example:

```
var refHighscore = db.ref("highscores/classic/alltime/{score}")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. This is a unique feature of Cloud Functions, as a trigger is registered directly with the Realtime Database itself. The Admin SDK functions just like the Client SDK -- no wildcards.

Comment: Oo this is a bummer :(